# List view with custom items

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, listviewitem

I am developing an application and I need an explanation on how can I realize a listview made of custom items like this:

[image]

How can I organize things like that? And what should I use?
(Sorry for the poor quality of the image)

Comment: Not sure but hope if this link helps - [Android Custom ListView with Image and Text using Volley](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/)

Answer (score 0):

A basic design for ListView item could be something like this

```
<ListView>
  <!-- container for the basic design -->
  <LinearLayout
     android:orientation="horizontal">
    <!-- Left side column -->
    <LinearLayout
     android:orientation="vertical">
       <ImageView />
       <TextView />
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Right side column -->
    <LinearLayout
     android:orientation="vertical">
       <TextView />
       <!-- add Text and 3 images in this LinearLayout -->
       <LinearLayout 
         android:orientation="horizontal" />
       <TextView />
    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
</ListView>
```

Then add your own custom adaptor to add the item in the ListView. Here is a good tutorial answer on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6860788/2777098

Answer (score 0):

You can use LinearLayout weigth.But its  not recommended for performance.There are other ways.Like grid .
Your Custom list item shoul be  like this.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_weight="0.7"
    android:background="@color/Black">
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_weight="1.3"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:background="@color/Red">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_weight="1.6">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:background="@color/Aqua">
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```